# Applying The Same Height For All DataGridColumns when MaxWidth of the Header Is Set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl containing dynamically changable number of DataGrids:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Table.Columns}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
      <local:ColumnTemplateSelector InputParameterColumnTemplate="{StaticResource InputParamterColumn}"
                                    SingleParameterColumnTemplate="{StaticResource SingleParameterColumn}"/>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

The template for the "SingleParameterColumn" is defined like this:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SingleParameterColumn">       
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}"      
                                   RowHeight="25" RowHeaderWidth="0" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                           MaxWidth="60">
                                </TextBlock>
                                <Button>
                                    <Image ... />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>....
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

There is always one `InputParameterColumn` and at least one `SingleParameterColumn`. The `InputParameterColumn` has a fixed header name, whereas the header of the `SingleParameterColumn` can be arbitrarily long.

Since I do not want to have very wide columns I have defined the `MaxWidth` of the `TextBlock` in the header template to 60, which causes the header to be higher if the name of a column is very long.

This causes the columns to have different heights depending on the length of the header name. 
[image: Here is the issue:]

Is there any way I can find out how tall is the tallest header in my ItemsControl and then set the same height for all the other headers so that my columns then all have the same size?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of what is being experienced?

Comment: Here is the screenshot: http://s14.postimg.org/kxhfvh9gh/Capture.png           I would like to have all headers the same height so the rows can be aligned.

Comment: This is weird, I just tried your code and my header cells were all the same size automatically... Have you edited the DataGrid template? Or is there anything on the HeaderTemplate that you're not showing us?

Comment: No, that is everything there is in the header template. Could you post your code so I can compare it to mine?

Comment: I just copied the DataGrid of your example to a new solution, copied the DataGridTemplateColumn two times and set a text directly to each TextBlock instead of using binding. Also used Items to add a couple strings, instead of binding ItemsSource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could finally reproduce your problem, and managed to solve it with these changes:

1. Set `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` on the StackPanel that serves as ItemsPanel for your ItemsControl
2. On you ItemTemplate, Change the StackPanels of the HeaderTemplates for Grids
3. On each Grid, define a single row with the same `SharedSizeGroup` identifier

ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Table.Columns}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
      <local:ColumnTemplateSelector InputParameterColumnTemplate="{StaticResource InputParamterColumn}"
                                    SingleParameterColumnTemplate="{StaticResource SingleParameterColumn}"/>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SingleParameterColumn">       
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Cells}"      
              RowHeight="25" RowHeaderWidth="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"
                                               SharedSizeGroup="DataGridHeaderRow" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                       TextAlignment="Center"
                                       MaxWidth="60">
                            </TextBlock>
                            <Button Grid.Column="1">
                                <Image ... />
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>....
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: No, this does not work, because my columns are not bound within one data grid, but each column is a datagrid on its own containing one template column.

Comment: Ok, I see, that's why I couldn't reproduce the problem. Let me try again and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Done. Managed to reproduce it and solve it with the code above... Instead of setting `IsSharedSizeScope` on the DataGrid, you have to set it on the StackPanel inside the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Thx for taking the time to solve this. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a behavior that attaches to the header `TextBlock`, and does the following:

- subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event
- store somewhere (static prop or helper class...) the largest size
- if this largest size changes, just change the height of all elements the behavior is attached to